# How to add a new textbox based on selection from a dropdown list using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a project where there is requirement to show a text box when you select "Other" field in the country and currency dropdown. Here's what I tried.

How do I show a text box when I select "Other" from the country or currency dropdown ? I tried it in many ways but somehow it's not working.

Comment: try logging the value to see what it's returning

Comment: It's not printing anything.

Comment: use ng-show="country=='Other'" in the textbox

Comment: I tried that ng-show="country=='Other'" but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-show="country=='OTHER'"` and `ng-show="currency=='OTHER'"` in div to get desired result.

```
 <div class="row">   
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Select Country</label>
                    <select ng-model="country">
                        <option value="">-- Select a Country --</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.code}}">{{country.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>  
                <div class="field"> 
                    <label>Select Currency</label>
                    <select ng-model="currency" onchange='CheckCurrency(this.value);'>
                        <option value="">-- Select a Currency --</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="currency in currencies" value="{{currency.code}}">{{currency.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="field" ng-show="country=='OTHER'">
                    <input type="text" name="country" id="country"/>
                </div>   
                <div class="field" ng-show="currency=='OTHER'">
                    <input type="text" name="currency" id="currency"/>
                </div> 
          </div>
```

Check plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2EmN4b?p=preview